# Flutter - unable to produce variable from data in Cloud Firestore - undefined name error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use a list from a Cloud Firestore document field (called `'a_ge_vi'`) to populate my DropdownMenu options. This takes the form of an array of strings (see attached image).[image]

However, when I try to produce the `List<String>` with data from Cloud Firestore and put it in the variable `_partyList2`, I get the error in the console of `Undefined name '_partyList2'`. I created a version of the list in Flutter and this works fine - it is shown as `_partyList`. But really I want to use the data from Cloud Firestore so I can change the values when I need to.

Can anyone help with why this isn't working?

PS. It is worth noting that this text widget `Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['q01']` does show q01, which is also a field in my Cloud Firestore document so I am connecting to the database.

I have the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rewardpolling/pages/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';

final responseInstance = Firestore.instance;
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

List<String> _partyList = <String>[
  "Conservatives",
  "Labour",
  "Liberal Democrats",
  "SNP",
  "Plaid Cymru",
  "The Brexit Party",
  "Other",
  "I would not vote"
];

class TestSurvey extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'TestSurvey';
  @override
  _TestSurveyState createState() => _TestSurveyState();
}

class _TestSurveyState extends State<TestSurvey> {
  var selectedParty, submittedParty, userid;

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('MySurveys')
        .document('FirestoreTestSurvey')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      List<String> _partyList2 = document.data['a_ge_vi'];
      print(_partyList2);
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff303841),
        title: Center(child: Text('Test Survey')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
              }),
        ],
        leading: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12), child: Text('  ')),
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: FormBuilder(
            key: _fbKey,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream:
                      Firestore.instance.collection('MySurveys').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data');
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data.documents[0]['q01'],
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: "Roboto",
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        DropdownButton(
                          items: _partyList2
                              .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
                                    child: Text(
                                      value,
                                      style:
                                          TextStyle(color: Color(0xff303841)),
                                    ),
                                    value: value,
                                  ))
                              .toList(),
                          onChanged: (selectedParty) {
                            setState(() {
                              submittedParty = selectedParty;
                            });
                          },
                          value: submittedParty,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          hint: Text(
                            'Please choose an option',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff303841)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                                child: Text('Submit Survey'),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  final FirebaseUser user =
                                      await _auth.currentUser();
                                  final String userid = user.uid;
                                  responseInstance
                                      .collection("testSurvey08052020")
                                      .add({
                                    "user_id": userid,
                                    "ge_vi": submittedParty,
                                    "submission_time": DateTime.now()
                                  });
                                })),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have defined the `List<String> _partyList2 = document.data['a_ge_vi'];` in the `initState`.Its an issue of scope as the rest of code doesn't have access to the variable _partyList2;

What you can do is define the variable in the `state` and then assign it in `initState`

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure where I should put `List<String> _partyList2 = document.data['a_ge_vi']` - is it under `class _TestSurveyState extends State<TestSurvey> {`?

Comment: You can declare the `List<String> _partyList2;` right after `var selectedParty, submittedParty, userid;` this declaration or anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Shubham this issue is due to scope, as `_partyList2` is only accessible in  method `initState`  the solution to this is add a variable that is accesible in other parts of the code and setting it to this value on `initState`.

I corrected the code and added below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rewardpolling/pages/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';

final responseInstance = Firestore.instance;
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

List<String> _partyList = <String>[
  "Conservatives",
  "Labour",
  "Liberal Democrats",
  "SNP",
  "Plaid Cymru",
  "The Brexit Party",
  "Other",
  "I would not vote"
];

class TestSurvey extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'TestSurvey';
  @override
  _TestSurveyState createState() => _TestSurveyState();
}

class _TestSurveyState extends State<TestSurvey> {
  var selectedParty, submittedParty, userid, usablePartyList;

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('MySurveys')
        .document('FirestoreTestSurvey')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      List<String> _partyList2 = document.data['a_ge_vi'];
      print(_partyList2);
      usablePartyList = _partyList2;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff303841),
        title: Center(child: Text('Test Survey')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
              }),
        ],
        leading: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12), child: Text('  ')),
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: FormBuilder(
            key: _fbKey,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream:
                      Firestore.instance.collection('MySurveys').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data');
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data.documents[0]['q01'],
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: "Roboto",
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        DropdownButton(
                          items: usablePartyList
                              .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
                                    child: Text(
                                      value,
                                      style:
                                          TextStyle(color: Color(0xff303841)),
                                    ),
                                    value: value,
                                  ))
                              .toList(),
                          onChanged: (selectedParty) {
                            setState(() {
                              submittedParty = selectedParty;
                            });
                          },
                          value: submittedParty,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          hint: Text(
                            'Please choose an option',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff303841)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                                child: Text('Submit Survey'),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  final FirebaseUser user =
                                      await _auth.currentUser();
                                  final String userid = user.uid;
                                  responseInstance
                                      .collection("testSurvey08052020")
                                      .add({
                                    "user_id": userid,
                                    "ge_vi": submittedParty,
                                    "submission_time": DateTime.now()
                                  });
                                })),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

flutter dart google-cloud-firestore
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @José Soni! However this won't start - I get the error 

`The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
_TestSurveyState.initState() returned a Future.

State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.

Rather than awaiting on asynchronous work directly inside of initState, call a separate method to do this work without awaiting it.`